# Matlab - Flag points using nearest neighbour search

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

I have the following problem and I am a bit clueless how to tackle it as my programming skills are very elementary ( I am an engineer, so please dont bite my head off).

[image]

**Problem**

I have a point cloud, the picture above displaying one level off it. Every point is a centroid off a block (x =5, y=1, z=5) and is specefied by carteisian coordinates. 
The centroids further have two values: one called "access" and one "product". If the product value is positive and pays for the access to the point I want to include it in my outcome. The red marker in the picture represents a possible starting point.

**Starting Idea**

As a start I am trying to set up an algorithm, that starts at the red marker, runs through the blocks left and right (along the x-axis), checks until where it would be feasible to access (so sum "product" > sum "access") and then goes to the next point (in y direction from marker) and does the same until the end of the level.

**Final Goal**

My final goal is that I can Flag points as accessed and the algorithm connects profitable "products" (so products that would pay for their access) on the shortest way to the access point (by setting blocks/points on the way to accessed).

I know this is a very open question and I apologize for that. I am just lacking a good starting point programming wise. I was thinking of `knnsearch`, but I am not sure if this is the right way to go as the blocks have different sizes and i technically want the nearest neighbour in every direction but also only one per direction.
Another idea I had was using `shortestpath` or creating a travel salesman problem out of it, but I am not sure how to properly implement it.

If you have any ideas or you could offer any help I would very much appreciate it. If any more information is needed I gladly provide it.